# CKQueryOperation visibility, cancellation and timeout possibilities

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

My application needs to run a CKQueryOperation using a CKDatabase.  This requires network access which is not always available.

Once I add a CKQueryOperation to the CKDatabase that’s about where my control stops.

Is there a way I can:

1. See of all pending operations specific to a CKDatabase.
2. Cancel an operation once I’ve added it to the CKDatabase?
3. Set a completion timeout so the operation doesn't stay pending if the network is preventing completion?

I know I can do this with CKDatabase performQuery however I would prefer to use operations if possible, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Regarding number 2: I haven't tried, but I think it is possible, as a) Apple says in the docs: "Any completion block you specify should be prepared to handle the failure of the operation to complete its task, whether due to an error or an explicit cancellation."  and b) as CKQueryOperation inherits from NSOperation. So may be you will (or did already ?) try [operation cancel].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For timeout you can set configuration object on the CKQueryOperation:

```
let config = CKOperation.Configuration()
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5

// Config operation
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.configuration = config
operation.other_stuff..
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (_, error: Error?) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // Handle timeout error here.
            return
        }
        ...
 }
```

Default timeout is 60 seconds.